# How to add a label to a Django admin field

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to add some helper text to the admin for data entry people who will take over.

Something like:
"Check the dropdown for a category before adding a new one."

Is django admin customization capable of doing this?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can read about [how to override templates in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates).

Comment: Sachin looks like you've shown another way to go ty. Completely viable but a bit too complex for my needs here. Going to mark JPGs answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add [**`help_text`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#help-text) in model as,

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField(help_text='My Help Text')
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: @DGG Beautiful is better than ugly ;)